# Updating Python3 and Pip3 on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pip

I have two versions of python3 installed on my computer. They are located here:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

I have set my PATH variable to use the first version. Running "which python3" routes to this version: /usr/local/bin/python3 -- this is what I want.

Unfortunately, pip3, and yet another version of Python, are installed in a different location (I think the version that comes pre-installed with mac). When I run "pip3 --version" I get the below:

```
pip 20.1.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Shouldn't these match? Is there a way to make sure python3 uses the pip3 version via /usr/local/bin/pip3? Do I just need to change / add it to my path somehow?

Another option is to uninstall everything with homebrew (what I used to originally install python3), and then reinstall. However, apparently, per my co-worker, we need to stay on python3.7. I'm worried if I reinstall python3, it will default to 3.8 or higher.

Please help!

Comment: first thing is to go to `usr/local/bin/python3` and see if it's just an alias to a file in a place you would expect it to be. the pip in `Library/Frameworks` isn't built in unless it's inside `System/Library`

Comment: @Tadhg - yes, usr/local/bin/python3 is just an alias.

Comment: so if you right click and do "show original" does it bring you to a file in the same folder as pip? it does for me.

Comment: just to clarify, do you have only 1 installation of `python 3.7` or are there multiple copies of the same version? If there is only 1 copy then if `pip3 --version` shows the right version I'm not sure why you would need to change anything.  And if all else fails `python3 -m pip` will always use the correct version of pip for what ever `python3` refers to.

Comment: yes, it does bring me to the same location as pip3: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python.3.7. So, I guess what I've described above is not the issue. Thanks for helping me with that. 

I am trying to run a python file that uses importlib to bring in config attributes for a given job. However, when I run this python file, I'm getting an error: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>". I was thinking it had to do with pip3 and python3 not being in the same location, but alas, that is not the issue. I think I'll create a different post that speaks to my issue more generally

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that I have found increase the chances of success here:

- don't mess with the Mac-installed default Python
- don't use homebrew to install Python
- use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to install and manage Python versions

Here's a useful write-up on [The right and wrong way to set Python 3 as default on a Mac](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac).

[image]